# Phonegap 2014 - How to calling java native code from Javascript ( Sencha Touch )

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I know this an an duplicate post for a question. But this time is 2014 ( and near 2015 ) and i new to Phonegap/Sencha Touch.

I want to call some java native code from phonegap using javascript ( in Sencha Touch ). On Google have many tutorial But they are out of date. Many tutorial for old version ( and now it's phone gap 3.5.0, sencha touch cmd 5 ).

Please suggest me some tutorial for calling java native code from an Sencha Touch project. Which for newest version.

Comment: Can you tell us what tutorials you've tried that you found out of date?

Comment: It's here: http://www.btek.com.au/calling-native-code-from-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to build your own PhoneGap plugin. The PhoneGap 3.5.0 documentation includes everything you need to get started:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I think create your own cordova plugin in java & call activity from that plugin. Do not forget to use callback function in cordova plugin.